# Retrieving a Java object (List) from a Win32 application

Tags: java, c++, c

I'm creating a Win32 application that controls another application which is coded in Java using AWT components. I figured that if I can retrieve the main List of the application and cast it with the JLIB library I'd be able to read its content.

First of all, am I right or I won't be able to get the real content of the List ? If I'm right I'd like to know how to achieve this since I didn't found any good spy software for Java and Spy++ only show a SunAwtComponent. Which I presume in the container for the whole Java application.

I'm not expecting someone to tell me how to do the whole thing but only a couple of direction would be really great since I've been looking for that for a while now.

Thanks for the replies !!!

Comment: Programs, ( with the possible exception of those written in Lisp ), don't have a 'main list' are you after a java.awt.List GUI component or a java.util.List?

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely the Java application actually uses Swing, not AWT. Swing draws its own widgets on top of a single AWTComponent, so the list widget that you see doesn't exist from Windows point of view.

I assume you cannot modify this Java application so that it can be controlled over some reasonable API (e.g. JMX or REST)?

You can try running the JVM with JPDA debugging interface enabled. You can then use JPDA APIs to change data structures and directly call methods on any object in that program. Finding the right ones to call will be hard, though.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html